# Automate Blueimp file upload - getting ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Tags: selenium, file-upload, automation, blueimp

i am trying to automate Blueimp file upload. but keep getting `ElementNotVisible` Exception.

```
WebElement fileUpload = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
String imagePath = "image.png";
fileUpload.sendKeys(imagePath);
```

I tried to enable using:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].checked = true;", fileUpload);`
```

but still no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to solve it would be to *make an element visible*:

```
WebElement fileUpload = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block'; arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';", fileUpload);

String imagePath = "image.png";
fileUpload.sendKeys(imagePath);
```

See also:

- [How to create javascript executor to make element visible in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371077/how-to-create-javascript-executor-to-make-element-visible-in-selenium-webdriver)
- [Selenium Webdriver - click on hidden elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363038/selenium-webdriver-click-on-hidden-elements)